# How can i open Modal by clicking the bar of a Bar Chart (Chart.JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chart.js

I'va a Bar Chart of Chart.js version 3.9.1
I want to click on a bar and a modal will open.
Please give someone the full chart and modal code

I've tried the Chart but can't implementing the Modal

```
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100"></canvas>

  <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button> -->




  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" onmouseover="myFunction()"
    onclick="alert('click event occurred')" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['Bothava', 'Sara', 'Bhimpur', 'Nuagan', 'Kidigaon-I'],

        datasets: [{
          label: 'In-Process',
          backgroundColor: '#EDA52D',
          borderRadius: 15,
          barThickness: 20,
          maxBarThickness: 40,
          data: [2.9, 0.9, 0, 0, 2.95]
        }, {
          label: 'Completed',
          backgroundColor: '#16BC2B',
          borderRadius: 15,
          barThickness: 20,
          maxBarThickness: 40,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 3.2, 0]
        }, {
          label: 'EoT',
          backgroundColor: '#0066CC',
          borderRadius: 15,
          barThickness: 20,
          maxBarThickness: 40,
          data: [0, 0, 2.4, 0, 0]
        }]

      },
      options: {

        scales: {
          y: {
            stacked: true,
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
              color: '#aaa'
            }
          }
        },
        indexAxis: 'y',
        responsive: true
      }
    });
  </script>
```

I can't make a modal for a bar
I'va a Bar Chart of Chart.js version 3.9.1
I want to click on a bar and a modal will open.
Please give someone the full chart and modal code